# How to Express a Feasible Region That is a Union of Sets in Scipy

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize-minimize

I am a newbie in optimization with scipy. I have a nonlinear problem where the feasible region is as follows:

[image: definition formula]

How can I express this region in scipy?

Defining a feasible region as the intersection of constraints is all I can do. But when it comes to  defining a region with the union operator, I am stuck.

Below is what i have came up with:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import NonlinearConstraint, Bounds, minimize


############ plot ############

# Define fesible region X
def in_region(x):
    return (x[0]**2 + x[1]**2 <= 4 and -2 <= x[0] <= 1 and -2 <= x[1] <= 1) or (-4 <= x[0] <= 0 and 0 <= x[1] <= 1) or (-4 <= x[1] <= 0 and 0 <= x[0] <= 1)

# Generate a grid of points to plot X
X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-4, 1, 500), np.linspace(-4, 1, 500))
Z = np.zeros_like(X)
for i in range(X.shape[0]):
    for j in range(X.shape[1]):
        Z[i,j] = in_region([X[i,j], Y[i,j]])

# Create a figure and plot X
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,8))
ax.pcolormesh(X, Y, Z, cmap='binary')

# Show the individual parts of the region
rect1 = Rectangle((-2,-2), 2, 2, linewidth=1, edgecolor='r', facecolor='none')
ax.add_patch(rect1)
rect2 = Rectangle((-4,0), 4, 1, linewidth=1, edgecolor='r', facecolor='none')
ax.add_patch(rect2)
rect3 = Rectangle((0,-4), 1, 4, linewidth=1, edgecolor='r', facecolor='none')
ax.add_patch(rect3)

# Set limits and labels
ax.set_xlim([-4, 1])
ax.set_ylim([-4, 1])
ax.set_xlabel('x[0]')
ax.set_ylabel('x[1]')


plt.show()

############ solve ############

# Define the objective function
def objective(x):
    return (x[0]+x[1])

# Define the feasible region
def constraint(x):
    if -4 <= x[0] <= -2: 
     return x[1]
    if 0<=x[0]<=1:
        return x[1]+4
    return  x[0]**2 + x[1]**2-4


# Define the bounds for the (x1, x2)
b = [(-4, 1), (-4, 1)]

# Define the constraints 
cons =  NonlinearConstraint(constraint,lb=0, ub=np.inf)

# Minimize the defined problem
result = minimize(objective, [0, 0], bounds=b, constraints=cons)

# Print (x1,x2)
print("The value of x1 at the minimum is:", result.x[0])
print("The value of x2 at the minimum is:", result.x[1])
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We aren't a code-writing writing service, so you'll need to start by reading the scipy documentation and then attempting to solve the problem yourself. Once you get stuck and have some of your own work to show, then ask a question about your *specific* problem. Here are some helpful resources: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: These regions are contiguous. Please show what you've tried.

Comment: Thank you for the welcoming and the warning. I am sincerely sorry. I will learn the rules better. I have edited my post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The upper, right and left constraints are univariate and constant. The bottom constraint can be modelled as a piecewise nonlinear constraint.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.axes import Axes
from scipy.optimize import minimize, Bounds, NonlinearConstraint


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax: Axes

'''
y^2 <= 4 - x^2
y <= +/- sqrt(4 - x^2)

x^2 + y^2 - 4 <= 0, -2 <= x <= 1, -2 <= y <= 1   |
                    -4 <= x <= 0,  0 <= y <= 1   |
                     0 <= x <= 1, -4 <= y <= 0
'''
x = np.linspace(start=-2, stop=1, num=100)
ax.fill_between(x, -np.sqrt(4 - x*x), np.ones_like(x), color='green')
ax.fill_between((-4, 0), ( 0,  0), (1, 1), color='blue')
ax.fill_between(( 0, 1), (-4, -4), (0, 0), color='red')
plt.show()


def objective(xy: np.ndarray) -> float:
    x, y = xy
    return x + y


def y_piecewise(xy: np.ndarray) -> float:
    x, y = xy
    if x < -2:
        return y
    if x >= 0:
        return y + 4
    return y + np.sqrt(4 - x**2)


result = minimize(
    fun=objective,
    x0=(0,0),
    bounds=Bounds(lb=(-4, -4), ub=(1, 1)),
    constraints=NonlinearConstraint(
        fun=y_piecewise, lb=0, ub=np.inf,
    ),
)
print(result)
```

[image: region]

Note that this is not on its own necessarily enough to produce a meaningful optimisation. Since the constraints are non-differentiable, the problem is sensitive to starting conditions.

Comment: Using @reinderien solution with `optimize.differential_evolution` should work, DE doesn't require differentiable constraints and is less sensitive to starting conditions.

Comment: Thank you @Reinderin. I have messed up in the g(x1,x2) part.

Comment: @andrew-nelson thanks. Using DE, obtained the optimal solution without worrying about the starting point.