# Scipy differential evolution - non-continuous bounds

Tags: python, scipy, genetic-algorithm, differential-evolution

I am trying to setup a `differential_evolution` algorithm.
I have approximately 15 variables, each with its own bounds (let's suppose they all share the same bounds `(150,250)`. I have successfully accomplished to do so.

Now, I would like to add the possibility for any parameter to be set to 0 (or any small number would be fine).

Is there any way that I could set the bounds for my parameters to be `(0,0.1) U (150, 250)`?
Can this be achieved through some kind of constraint?

Comment: In linear programming this is called a semicontinuous variable, but you've offered absolutely no information on your objective so it's impossible to say whether this would be applicable. But note that scipy's differential evolution does support integral variables, so it is indeed possible to express this directly (not that it's guaranteed to work well).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75997370/how-to-express-a-feasible-region-that-is-a-union-of-sets-in-scipy

Answer (score 0):

Here's a wild guess. It's enough to configure `differential_evolution` for the kind of constraint you want. It isn't enough to run a meaningful optimization, but there's no sense in tuning for an objective function that you haven't provided.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import differential_evolution, LinearConstraint


def objective(x: np.ndarray) -> float:
    a, b, a_selected, b_selected = x
    return a*b


constraint = LinearConstraint(
    A=(
        (1, 0, -150,    0),  # a >= 150s
        (1, 0, -250,    0),  # a <= 250s
        (0, 1,    0, -150),  # b >= 150t
        (0, 1,    0, -250),  # b <= 250t
    ),
    lb=(0, -np.inf, 0, -np.inf),
    ub=(+np.inf, 0, +np.inf, 0),
)

result = differential_evolution(
    func=objective,
    bounds=(
        (0, 250),
        (0, 250),
        (0, 1),
        (0, 1),
    ),
    integrality=(False, False, True, True),
    constraints=constraint,
)
assert result.success, result.message
a, b, a_selected, b_selected = result.x
print(f'a = {np.round(a, 3)}, selected: {a_selected}')
print(f'b = {np.round(b, 3)}, selected: {b_selected}')
print(f'f = {np.round(result.fun, 3)}')
```

Comment: The complex thing for me is that I am using parameters that come out of openseespy, which is a library for structural engineering calculations. Anyway I will try now to set the non linear piecewise constraint, thanks

Comment: Why are the constraints useful in this example? Aren't they the same thing as bounds?

Comment: The first two bounds are redundant but the second two bounds are necessary